# Charindex in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, charindex

There was a problem i had to find the solution for which was :
1) Ignore data breaks where the same PB SAP ID is present in Avaloq data multiple times and same value is present in CRM.
The PB SAP ID is a field which should be unique. Avaloq and CRM are two different systems that store similar data.

My colleague suggested the following SQL was the solution and it seems to work, but i do not understand how this is working in this case. Can someone please explain from the SQL below :

P.S. `cpp = crm system` and `ap. = Avaloq`

```
where  charindex(cpp.PbSapId,ap.Pb_SapId) =0
```

Comment: Sample data would really help non-colleagues understand what you want to do.

Comment: as if you are saying where the Avaloq ID is not present in the CRM id (i.e. you are finding the missing records only)

Comment: Providing Table Schema and sample data will help

Comment: It simply means that `ap.Pb_SapId` does not contain the string `cpp.PbSapId`. Whether it is a good suggestion or not cannot be determined.

Comment: If length of different PB SAP ID's can be different, then it is not a good solution. Because, for example, charindex('23456789','123456789') returns 2, though the values are not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Charindex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) returns the position of a substring within a string - in this case, the character position of the ap.Pb_SapID that contains the cpp.PBSapId. The 'where' '= 0' ultimately means you a searching for records where the ID is not within the ID of the other table.